# Model I/O mesh from custom data

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, metal, arkit

I am trying to create a MDLMesh from my own custom data that I parsed from a file. The file only contains vertices positions and triangles indexes ; I extract them into two Swift `Data` objects, `float3` format for vertices and `uint32` format for indexes.

My problem is that my MDLMesh doesn't seem to work properly as I can't import it to SceneKit (the resulting SCNGeometry seems "empty") nor create normals from it (crashes).

Now here is the code for MDLMesh:

```
 let mesh = MDLMesh()
        mesh.vertexBuffers = [MDLMeshBufferData(type: .vertex, data: vertexData)]
        mesh.vertexCount = floats.count/3
        let vertexDescriptor = MDLVertexDescriptor()
        let attribute = MDLVertexAttribute(name: MDLVertexAttributePosition, format: .float3, offset: 0, bufferIndex: 0)
        let layout = MDLVertexBufferLayout(stride: MemoryLayout<float3>.stride)
        vertexDescriptor.attributes = [attribute]
        vertexDescriptor.layouts = [layout]
```

Then I create a sub mesh (that describes the triangles) :

```
let submesh = MDLSubmesh(indexBuffer:  MDLMeshBufferData(type: MDLMeshBufferType.index, data: indexData),
           indexCount: uint32Indexes.count-uint32Indexes.count/4,
           indexType: .uint32,
           geometryType: .triangles,
           material: nil)

mesh.submeshes = [submesh]
```

**Do you see anything wrong ? Or could it just be that my data isn't correct ?**
Thank you

NB: Note that `indexCount` and `vertexCount` are both right even tough their definition seems weird without more context :)

EDIT:  When trying to make normals:

```
mesh.addNormals(withAttributeNamed: MDLVertexAttributeNormal, creaseThreshold: 0)
```

Here is the error I get:

> 2017-08-04 09:39:24.078436+0200 MyAppName[506:70657] *** Terminating
>   app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '***
>   -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndexedSubscript:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'

Answer (score 1):

You should remove layout from `VertexDescriptor`:

these lines:

```
let layout = MDLVertexBufferLayout(stride: MemoryLayout<float3>.stride)
vertexDescriptor.layouts = [layout]
```

And add these lines at the end of setting `VertexDescriptor`:

```
vertexDescriptor.setPackedOffsets()
vertexDescriptor.setPackedStrides()
```

Answer (score 0):

[Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/modelio/mdlmesh/1391284-addnormals#discussion) on this method states: "Calling this method on a mesh that does not contain vertex position data raises an exception.", and I believe that it is exactly the issue here: your vertexData seems to have no elements in it.

Comment: I should probably add an answer now that I solved my problem! The issue apparently was that I was providing the data before adding a description, so when I added the data everything was replace by default values of description !